# How do I get hex value for field categoryhex on creating category?

Tags: 7

I want to create a new category to my Drupal site but I need to set an `categoryhex` but I don't know which value I need to set here.

[image: Field categoryhex is required]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That hexadecimal value of the color. You can get the hex value of the color from here - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp
http://www.color-hex.com/color-names.html